# Enable High Contrast Mode in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, windows-10, high-contrast

I'm trying to make a .exe file in Visual that enables High Contrast Mode. I read

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa
and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-taghighcontrasta

up and down but I can't find a complete answer. What goes in the `uiParam` and `pvParam`? Please tell me where you found the answer!

`SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETHIGHCONTRAST, , , SPIF_SENDCHANGE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> uiParam
>
> Type: UINT
>
> A parameter whose usage and format depends on the system parameter
>   being queried or set. For more information about system-wide
>   parameters, see the uiAction parameter. If not otherwise indicated,
>   you must specify zero for this parameter.

You'll use 0 for this.

> pvParam
>
> Type: PVOID
>
> Sets the parameters of the HighContrast accessibility feature. The
>   pvParam parameter must point to a HIGHCONTRAST structure that contains
>   the new parameters.

You'll need a HIGHCONTRAST structure for this parameter, with the data you'd like to pass.

That means you'll do:

```
HIGHCONTRAST hc;
ZeroMemory(&hc, sizeof(HIGHCONTRAST));
hc.cbSize = sizeof(HIGHCONTRAST);
hc.dwFlags = HCF_HIGHCONTRASTON;
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETHIGHCONTRAST, 0, &hc, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

As a side note, you likely want to return the Windows environment back to the same state that it was in when your application started.

You should call SystemParametersInfo with SPI_GETHIGHCONTRAST before you change it, store away that HIGHCONTRAST struct for later, then restore the system to that HIGHCONTRAST struct when your application exits.

Comment: I'm kind of new to C++. How would I do this and what does it mean/do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about.

Comment: How would I switch it back? Would it be

`
HIGHCONTRAST hc;
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETHIGHCONTRAST, 0, &hc, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETHIGHCONTRAST, 0, &hc, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
`?

Comment: Yep, that'll do. Stash the `hc` that you obtained from your SPI_GETHIGHCONTRAST call until you're ready to restore it. Might want to call it `hcOriginal` to make it obvious what it is for.

Comment: Could and how would I store the high contrast variable and keep it for later in a file and be retrieved? I'm looking to turn it on and off with separate programs.

Comment: @Dubstep I'd ask that as a separate question.